# SQL Server Get row value when using MAX

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which holds a date field and an integer field like the example below:

```
Date          Number
01/01/2017    9
02/01/2017    13
03/01/2017    16
04/01/2017    2
15/01/2017    4
20/01/2017    8    
27/01/2017    1
```

I want to write a query selecting the MAX(date) where the date is <= 13/01/2017 (which would give me 04/01/2017) and return the number column value associated with it (2 in this example)..  I can of course write 2 queries getting one and using the result to find the next but I hope there is another way using only one statement.  It probably would help if I knew how to word this so I haven't had much luck searching for a solution..

Thank you in advance..

Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TOP 1` and `Order By`

```
select Top 1 * from yourtable where [date] <= CONVERT(DATE, '13/01/2017', 103) 
order by date desc
```

Better to use `yyyy-mm-dd` format for your date input